# How to close language option frame in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, escaping

I want to skip the language selection through Selenium Webdriver. This could be by pressing escape from keyboard or clicking on the save button. I am failing to do either of these.
Can anyone help in this regard ?

```
//driver.switchTo().alert();
//button[@id='save_language']
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, you could add a screenshot and the page's HTLM to expand the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's more like an alert.

Try with this code :

```
Alert a =  driver.switchTo().alert();
a.accept();
```

After accepting the alert, you will have to switch back the focus of web driver to default. For that you will need :

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: It says "no such alert".

Comment: Ok, Could you share the HTML code of the dialogue box ?

Comment: Its a model box not alert. I am unable to paste the model box code here. Its exceeding the limit.

Comment: You can update the question with that code . There's a option to edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Actions** class,which is basically used for input interactions (Ex: Keyboard and mouse interactions)
You need to import following package for it.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Then create a Actions class object and use it to send escape keys.

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();
```

Hope it helps !